# How to fix a Failed Task for a Biml-Built SSIS Script Task: No such interface supported

Tags: c#, ssis, biml

I've been testing out creating script tasks through Biml for SSIS packages.
I want to be able to locally execute/test packages successfully.

I was unable to execute the packages for a project from my local development environment, as they all error with the same error below.

**Issue:**
`Error: 0x0 at ScriptTask 1, Script Task : Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSVariables100'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{2CD38B23-6C17-4025-A8B6-D2E497DD1DDC}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.get_Item(Object index)
   at ScriptMain.Main()
Error: 0x6 at ScriptTask 1: The script returned a failure result.
Task failed: ScriptTask 1`

I was able to execute these packages successfully from another server after doing a project deployment from Visual Studio to the SSIS catalog (SSISDB) on that server (SQL Server 2016).

I used the following references for the AssemblyInfo and ScriptMain:

- Varigence Documentation code sample:
  https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Samples/Biml/Script+Task+Project
- BimlScript code sample: http://bimlscript.com/Snippet/Details/74

```xml
<Script ProjectCoreName="ST_232fecafb70a4e8a904cc21f8870eed0" Name="ScriptTask 1">
    <ScriptTaskProject>
        <ScriptTaskProject ProjectCoreName="ST_c41ad4bf47544c49ad46f4440163feae" Name="TaskScriptProject1">
            <AssemblyReferences>
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.dll" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.AddIn.dll" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data.dll" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Windows.Forms.dll" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml.dll" />
            </AssemblyReferences>
            <Files>
                <File Path="AssemblyInfo.cs">
                    using System.Reflection;
                    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

                    //
                    // General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following
                    // set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
                    // associated with an assembly.
                    //
                    [assembly: AssemblyTitle("ST_c41ad4bf47544c49ad46f4440163feae.csproj")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyCompany("Varigence")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyProduct("ST_c41ad4bf47544c49ad46f4440163feae.csproj")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright @ Varigence 2013")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
                    //
                    // Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
                    //
                    //      Major Version
                    //      Minor Version
                    //      Build Number
                    //      Revision
                    //
                    // You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers
                    // by using the '*' as shown below:

                    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
                </File>
                <File Path="ScriptMain.cs">
                    using System;
                    using System.Data;
                    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
                    using System.Windows.Forms;

                    // if SSIS2012, use the following line:
                    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]

                    // if earlier version, use the next line instead of the above line:
                    // [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
                    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
                    {
                        enum ScriptResults
                        {
                            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
                            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
                        };

                        public void Main()
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int totalInsertedRowsToDestination = (int)Dts.Variables["User::TotalInsertedRowsToDestination"].Value;
                                int rowCountNew = (int)Dts.Variables["User::RowCountNew"].Value;
                                int totalUpdatedRowsToDestination = (int)Dts.Variables["User::TotalUpdatedRowsToDestination"].Value;
                                int rowCountChanged = (int)Dts.Variables["User::RowCountChanged"].Value;
                                int totalUnChangedRowsToDestination = (int)Dts.Variables["User::TotalUnChangedRowsToDestination"].Value;
                                int rowCountUnchanged = (int)Dts.Variables["User::RowCountUnchanged"].Value;

                                totalInsertedRowsToDestination += rowCountNew;
                                totalUpdatedRowsToDestination += rowCountChanged;
                                totalUnChangedRowsToDestination += rowCountUnchanged;

                                Dts.Variables["User::TotalInsertedRowsToDestination"].Value = totalInsertedRowsToDestination;
                                Dts.Variables["User::TotalUpdatedRowsToDestination"].Value = totalUpdatedRowsToDestination;
                                Dts.Variables["User::TotalUnChangedRowsToDestination"].Value = totalUnChangedRowsToDestination;

                                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script Task ", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
                                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                            }
                        }                                   
                    }
                </File>
            </Files>
            <ReadOnlyVariables>
                <Variable Namespace="User" DataType="Int32" VariableName="RowCountNew" />
                <Variable Namespace="User" DataType="Int32" VariableName="RowCountChanged" />
                <Variable Namespace="User" DataType="Int32" VariableName="RowCountUnchanged" />
            </ReadOnlyVariables>
            <ReadWriteVariables>
                <Variable Namespace="User" DataType="Int32" VariableName="TotalInsertedRowsToDestination" />
                <Variable Namespace="User" DataType="Int32" VariableName="TotalUpdatedRowsToDestination" />
                <Variable Namespace="User" DataType="Int32" VariableName="TotalUnChangedRowsToDestination" />
            </ReadWriteVariables>
        </ScriptTaskProject>
    </ScriptTaskProject>
    <PrecedenceConstraints>
        <Inputs>
          <Input OutputPathName="SQL Update <#=dstTableName#>.Output" />
        </Inputs>
    </PrecedenceConstraints>
</Script>
```

I expect the output to be: `SSIS package finished: Success` without errors in the script task.

My environment:

- `Windows 10 Enterprise 6.3 x64`
- `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (integrated): 14.0.23107.0`
- `Microsoft .NET Framework: 4.7.03056`
- `BimlExpress: 1.0`
- `SQL Server Data Tools: 14.0.61705.170`
- `SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR): 13.0.4224.16(x64)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the error locally on multiple different environments/machines and identified a fix.

**Resolution:** Change the SSIS project's *TargetServerVersion* from `SQL Server 2014` to `SQL Server 2016`.
The *resulting* message after running the package is `SSIS package finished: Success`.

**Why:**

Something in these environments is missing needed pieces to work with a TargetServerVersion of SQL Server 2014 related to the IDTSVariables100 Interface. That interface relates to SQL Server .NET SDK 2017 2016.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.wrapper.idtsvariables100?view=sqlserver-2017

About TargetServerVersion and ProjectVersion, Andy Leonard explains in his blog post,

> *"the TargetServerVersion property can be used to maintain the current Production version of an SSIS project using the latest tools, as long as the current Production version is SSIS 2012+. And the TargetServerVersion property can be updated to the latest version available by simply changing the value in a dropdown"*.
>   https://andyleonard.blog/2018/08/a-tale-of-two-properties-ssis-projectversion-and-targetserverversion/

```xml
<ProductVersion>14.0.600.250</ProductVersion>
```

More thoughts are below in the *Additional References for SSDT* section.

**How-to:**

1. Right click on the SSIS project *[MySsisProject (SQL Server 2014)]* in Visual Studio and select Properties.

[image: select Properties of SSIS project]

2. Within the newly opened Property Page, expand the Configuration Properties group and select General. Then select the appropriate TargetServerVersion (SQL Server 2016 in my situation)

[image: select TargetServerVersion]

3. Read the warning, mentioning possible issues with extensions and determine if you want to proceed.

[image: TargetServerVersion Change Warning]

Now the the SSIS project has SQL Server 2016 in parentheses after the project name, `MySsisProject (SQL Server 2016)`. This resolves the issue.
Next, execute the package locally to verify the successful package completion.

**Tested Environments/Machines:**

1. Environment :

   - `Windows 10 Enterprise 6.3 x64`
   - `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (integrated): 14.0.23107.0`
   - `Microsoft .NET Framework: 4.7.03056`
   - `BimlExpress: 1.0`
   - `SQL Server Data Tools: 14.0.61705.170`
   - `SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR): 13.0.4224.16(x64)`
2. Environment :

   - `Windows 10 Enterprise 6.3 x64`
   - `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017: 15.9.8`
   - `Microsoft .NET Framework: 4.7.03056`
   - `BimlExpress: 1.0`
   - `SQL Server Data Tools: 15.1.61902.21100`
   - `SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR): 13.0.4224.16(x64)`
3. Environment :

   - `Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 x64`
   - `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015: 14.0.25431.01 Update 3`
   - `Microsoft .NET Framework: 4.7.02053`
   - `BimlExpress: 1.0`
   - `SQL Server Data Tools: 14.0.61705.170`
   - `SQL Server 2016 (SP1): 13.0.4001.0(x64)`

**Additional Reference for SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools):**

- SSDT is designed to be backwards compatible and Information on installing SSDT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017
- Examples of Script Tasks failing and then an SSDT release (15.9.0 tied to VS 2017) fixing the issue:
  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896399-script-tasks-losing-code-in-ssdt-17-1-for-visual-s
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/release-notes-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-visual-studio-2017-1570
- I found a similar issue related to "SSIS Script Task - No Interface Supported" relating to a version difference, with a fix of loading an older version; however, the answer was limited and did not describe the needed resolution of the identified issue for the above question: 
  [SSIS Script Task - No Interface Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384669/ssis-script-task-no-interface-supported)

Answer (score 0):

We had some environment issues as well after we decided to remove the different paths.
As some had a dll in GAC and others only in Visual Studio PublicAssemblies directory

We still wanted to remove the path, but still needed to give a hint about the target version.

We now fixed it within Biml doing the assembly references like this:

```
<AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=x86, Custom=null" />
```

And to make it more re-usable for other dll's like this:

```
<# int MajorSQLVersion  = 13; #>
<AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=<#= MajorSQLVersion.ToString() #>.0.0.0" />
```